# Font background color not working properly

Tags: html, css, background-color

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: white;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #000000, #ffffff, #ffffff, #000000);
  line-height:25px;
}
h2{
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    padding-left: 14px;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: normal;
    background-color: orange;
}

p{
    margin: auto;
    width: 32%;
    color: black;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    padding-bottom: 14px;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

form{
    margin: auto;
    width: 32%;
    color: black;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
     
}

input[type=text], select {
  display: block;
  margin: 8px 0;
}
input[type=date], select {
  display: block;
  margin: 8px 0;
}
input[type=submit], select {
  margin-left: 50%;
  margin-top: 10%
}

.nadpis{
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    padding-left: 14px;
    font-size: 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="cs">
    <head>
        <title>Hlavní stránka</title>
        <link rel='icon' href='favicon.ico?' type='image/x-icon'/>
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <style></style>                                                       
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="nadpis">Vítejte v online dotazníku</h1>
        <h2>Vyplnění tohoto formuláře pomůže mé práci</h2>
        <br>

        <form action="https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ">
            <label>
              Jméno:<input type="text" name="jmeno" required />
            </label>

            <label>
              Příjmení:<input type="text" name="prijmeni" required />
            </label>



            Pohlaví:
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="pohlavi" value="muz" required>
            <label for="muz">Muž</label><br>
            <input type="radio" name="pohlavi" value="zena">
            <label for="zena">Žena</label><br>

            <label>
            Datum narození:<input type="date" name="narozeniny" required />
            </label>

        <h2>Teď k Vašim preferencím</h2>

            Kde všude hrajete hry:
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="pc" value="pc">
            <label for="pc">Počítač</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="konzole" value="konzole">
            <label for="konzole">Konzole</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="mobile" value="Telefon">
            <label for="mobile">Telefon</label><br>

            Jak moc jste spokojeni s vládními opatřeními:
            <br>
            <label>
                <input type="range" name="spoko" min="0" max="50" required>
            </label><br>


            Vyberte vaši oblíbenou barvu:
            <br>
            <label>
                <input type="color" name="barva">
            </label>           

            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to do a simple form page for a school project.
The code is somehow completed, I already sent it but now I am just trying to make it look better - I added some background-color: orange to h2 just to test it out but it doesn't really work properly.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: white;
  line-height: 25px;
}

h2 {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  padding-left: 14px;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  background-color: orange;
}

p {
  margin: auto;
  width: 32%;
  color: black;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  padding-bottom: 14px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

form {
  margin: auto;
  width: 32%;
  color: black;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

input[type=text],
select {
  display: block;
  margin: 8px 0;
}

input[type=date],
select {
  display: block;
  margin: 8px 0;
}

input[type=submit],
select {
  margin-left: 50%;
  margin-top: 10%
}

.nadpis {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  padding-left: 14px;
  font-size: 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="cs">

  <head>

    <title>Hlavní stránka</title>
    <link rel='icon' href='favicon.ico?' type='image/x-icon' />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style></style>


  </head>

  <body>
    <h1 class="nadpis">Vítejte v online dotazníku</h1>
    <h2>Vyplnění tohoto formuláře pomůže mé práci</h2>
    <br>



    <form action="https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ">
      <label>
          Jméno:<input type="text" name="jmeno" required />
      </label>

      <label>
          Příjmení:<input type="text" name="prijmeni" required />
      </label> Pohlaví:
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="pohlavi" value="muz" required>
      <label for="muz">Muž</label><br>
      <input type="radio" name="pohlavi" value="zena">
      <label for="zena">Žena</label><br>

      <label>
          Datum narození:<input type="date" name="narozeniny" required />
      </label>

      <h2>Teď k Vašim preferencím</h2>

      Kde všude hrajete hry:
      <br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="pc" value="pc">
      <label for="pc">Počítač</label><br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="konzole" value="konzole">
      <label for="konzole">Konzole</label><br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="mobile" value="Telefon">
      <label for="mobile">Telefon</label><br> Jak moc jste spokojeni s vládními opatřeními:
      <br>
      <label>
          <input type="range" name="spoko" min="0" max="50" required>
      </label><br> Vyberte vaši oblíbenou barvu:
      <br>
      <label>
          <input type="color" name="barva">
      </label>

      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

  </body>

</html>
```

As you can see, first h2 text has whole page background color and h2 in form has the text only in white background of the page...
I'd be more than glad for any tip even about other code, thanks.

Comment: I am not sure what your question is... What is the problem? You want just the first `h2` to be colred? Please clarify!

Comment: The form has `width: 32%`, so if you put an `h2` into it, it will have the full width of the form (which is 32% of the body in this case) - all this works as expected.

Comment: I am sorry, I accidentaly removed this code from the body > background: linear-gradient(to right, #000000, #ffffff, #ffffff, #000000);

Comment: I would like to have h2's background colored and its width should be the same lenght as the white color of the background if you can understand that haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your last comment you want the first `h2` only be as wide as the `h2` which is inside the form. Since the form is 32% wide, you can add this rule:

```
body>h2 {
  width: 32%;
  margin-left: 34%;
}
```

This will define the width of all `h2`s which are direct children of the `body` as 32% and center it (with a `margin-left` of 34%, which is 100% minus 32% divided by 2):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: white;
  line-height: 25px;
}

h2 {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  padding-left: 14px;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  background-color: orange;
}

body>h2 {
  width: 32%;
  margin-left: 34%;
}

p {
  margin: auto;
  width: 32%;
  color: black;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  padding-bottom: 14px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

form {
  margin: auto;
  width: 32%;
  color: black;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

input[type=text],
select {
  display: block;
  margin: 8px 0;
}

input[type=date],
select {
  display: block;
  margin: 8px 0;
}

input[type=submit],
select {
  margin-left: 50%;
  margin-top: 10%
}

.nadpis {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  padding-left: 14px;
  font-size: 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="cs">

<head>

  <title>Hlavní stránka</title>
  <link rel='icon' href='favicon.ico?' type='image/x-icon' />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style></style>


</head>

<body>
  <h1 class="nadpis">Vítejte v online dotazníku</h1>
  <h2>Vyplnění tohoto formuláře pomůže mé práci</h2>
  <br>



  <form action="https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ">
    <label>
          Jméno:<input type="text" name="jmeno" required />
      </label>

    <label>
          Příjmení:<input type="text" name="prijmeni" required />
      </label> Pohlaví:
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="pohlavi" value="muz" required>
    <label for="muz">Muž</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="pohlavi" value="zena">
    <label for="zena">Žena</label><br>

    <label>
          Datum narození:<input type="date" name="narozeniny" required />
      </label>

    <h2>Teď k Vašim preferencím</h2>

    Kde všude hrajete hry:
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="pc" value="pc">
    <label for="pc">Počítač</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="konzole" value="konzole">
    <label for="konzole">Konzole</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mobile" value="Telefon">
    <label for="mobile">Telefon</label><br> Jak moc jste spokojeni s vládními opatřeními:
    <br>
    <label>
          <input type="range" name="spoko" min="0" max="50" required>
      </label><br> Vyberte vaši oblíbenou barvu:
    <br>
    <label>
          <input type="color" name="barva">
      </label>

    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: holy, that worked 100%, thank you very much, i didnt know that you can do this kind of stuff in css!

Answer (score 0):

you can add first `h2` in one div and add css as per this div like this `.heading h2{background-color: orange;}`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: white;
  line-height:25px;
}
h2{
  color: black;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  padding-left: 14px;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: normal;  
}

.heading {
  text-align: center;
}

.heading h2 {
  background-color: orange;
}


p{
  margin: auto;
  width: 32%;
  color: black;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  padding-bottom: 14px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

form{
  margin: auto;
  width: 32%;
  color: black;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;

}

input[type=text], select {
  display: block;
  margin: 8px 0;
}
input[type=date], select {
  display: block;
  margin: 8px 0;
}
input[type=submit], select {
  margin-left: 50%;
  margin-top: 10%
}
.nadpis{
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  padding-left: 14px;
  font-size: 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<h1 class="nadpis">Vítejte v online dotazníku</h1>
<div class="heading"><h2>Vyplnění tohoto formuláře pomůže mé práci</h2></div>
<br>
<form action="https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ">
    <label>
    Jméno:<input type="text" name="jmeno" required />
    </label>

    <label>
    Příjmení:<input type="text" name="prijmeni" required />
    </label>
    Pohlaví:
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="pohlavi" value="muz" required>
    <label for="muz">Muž</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="pohlavi" value="zena">
    <label for="zena">Žena</label><br>

    <label>
    Datum narození:<input type="date" name="narozeniny" required />
    </label>

    <h2>Teď k Vašim preferencím</h2>

    Kde všude hrajete hry:
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="pc" value="pc">
    <label for="pc">Počítač</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="konzole" value="konzole">
    <label for="konzole">Konzole</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mobile" value="Telefon">
    <label for="mobile">Telefon</label><br>

    Jak moc jste spokojeni s vládními opatřeními:
    <br>
    <label>
    <input type="range" name="spoko" min="0" max="50" required>
    </label><br>
    Vyberte vaši oblíbenou barvu:
    <br>
    <label>
    <input type="color" name="barva">
    </label>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form width is 32% and ur `<h2>` tag is inside your form hence explains the background only covers 32% of it. Alternatively, you can use `<div>` to wrap your content and use `flexbox` and `justify-content` to make it center.

I have attached the sample code below. You can further add CSS to style it further such as margins and padding.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="cs">
<head>
  
    <title>Hlavní stránka</title>
            <link rel='icon' href='favicon.ico?' type='image/x-icon'/>
            <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
margin: 0;
background-color: white;

line-height:25px;
}
h2{
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    padding-left: 14px;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: normal;
    background-color: orange;
}


p{
    margin: auto;
    width: 32%;
    color: black;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    padding-bottom: 14px;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

form{
    margin: auto;
    
    color: black;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
     
}

input[type=text], select {
display: block;
margin: 8px 0;
}
input[type=date], select {
display: block;
margin: 8px 0;
}
input[type=submit], select {
margin-left: 50%;
margin-top: 10%
}



.nadpis{
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    padding-left: 14px;
    font-size: 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}

                                                                    



</style>                                                                            

  
</head>
    <body>
            <h1 class="nadpis">Vítejte v online dotazníku</h1>
            <h2>Vyplnění tohoto formuláře pomůže mé práci</h2>
            <br>
            
    
    
            <form action="https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ">
                <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center;"> 
                    <div>                
                        <label>
                        Jméno:<input type="text" name="jmeno" required />
                        </label>
                    
                        <label>
                        Příjmení:<input type="text" name="prijmeni" required />
                        </label>

                        Pohlaví:
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="pohlavi" value="muz" required>
                        <label for="muz">Muž</label><br>
                        <input type="radio" name="pohlavi" value="zena">
                        <label for="zena">Žena</label><br>
                        
                        <label>
                        Datum narození:<input type="date" name="narozeniny" required />
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <h2>Teď k Vašim preferencím</h2>
                <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center;"> 
                    <div>
                        Kde všude hrajete hry:
                        <br>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="pc" value="pc">
                        <label for="pc">Počítač</label><br>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="konzole" value="konzole">
                        <label for="konzole">Konzole</label><br>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="mobile" value="Telefon">
                        <label for="mobile">Telefon</label><br>
                        
                        Jak moc jste spokojeni s vládními opatřeními:
                        <br>
                        <label>
                        <input type="range" name="spoko" min="0" max="50" required>
                        </label><br>
                        
                        
                        Vyberte vaši oblíbenou barvu:
                        <br>
                        <label>
                        <input type="color" name="barva">
                        </label>
                        
                        
                    </div>
                </div> 
              
            
                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
 
  
            

        


    </body>
</html>
```

This code below make the `<h2>` tag smaller

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="cs">
<head>
  
    <title>Hlavní stránka</title>
            <link rel='icon' href='favicon.ico?' type='image/x-icon'/>
            <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
margin: 0;
background-color: white;

line-height:25px;
}
h2{
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    padding-left: 14px;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: normal;
    background-color: orange;
}


p{
    margin: auto;
    width: 32%;
    color: black;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    padding-bottom: 14px;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

form{
    margin: auto;
    width: 32%;
    color: black;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
     
}

input[type=text], select {
display: block;
margin: 8px 0;
}
input[type=date], select {
display: block;
margin: 8px 0;
}
input[type=submit], select {
margin-left: 50%;
margin-top: 10%
}



.nadpis{
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    padding-left: 14px;
    font-size: 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}

                                                                    



</style>                                                                            

  
</head>
    <body>
            
            
    
    
            <form action="https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ">
                <h1 class="nadpis">Vítejte v online dotazníku</h1>
            <h2>Vyplnění tohoto formuláře pomůže mé práci</h2>
            <br>
                <label>
                Jméno:<input type="text" name="jmeno" required />
                </label>
            
                <label>
                Příjmení:<input type="text" name="prijmeni" required />
                </label>
              
                
              
                Pohlaví:
                <br>
                <input type="radio" name="pohlavi" value="muz" required>
                <label for="muz">Muž</label><br>
                <input type="radio" name="pohlavi" value="zena">
                <label for="zena">Žena</label><br>
                
                <label>
                Datum narození:<input type="date" name="narozeniny" required />
                </label>

            <h2>Teď k Vašim preferencím</h2>
                
                Kde všude hrajete hry:
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="pc" value="pc">
                <label for="pc">Počítač</label><br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="konzole" value="konzole">
                <label for="konzole">Konzole</label><br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="mobile" value="Telefon">
                <label for="mobile">Telefon</label><br>
                
                Jak moc jste spokojeni s vládními opatřeními:
                <br>
                <label>
                <input type="range" name="spoko" min="0" max="50" required>
                </label><br>
                
                
                Vyberte vaši oblíbenou barvu:
                <br>
                <label>
                <input type="color" name="barva">
                </label>
                
                
                
              
            
                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
  
  
            

        


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works nicely but I'd like the opposite of it! I want the background thinner not larger!
I am sorry, i dont have 15 reputation so i cannot upvote:(

Comment: Hey there, its okay. You can marked it as the correct answer as well if I solved your question. Just move the `<h2>` tag into the form. Since the form has a width of 32%, your `<h2>` tag background color will be 32% as well